# Change max length and IsRequired to many entity in one shut

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Is a .net core 2 project in c#
I use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (2.0.0) Code First approach...
I have 20  entity in my DbCcontext that have couple column in same structure...
I want make it IsRequired and have a maximum length  of 40
I prefer use the FluentApi

I want to know if I can avoid the repitation of the same block over and over to do that

eg

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<LocationType>()
            .Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(40);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(40);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
            .Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(40);
        modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
            .Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(40);
        //Is will continu like for 20 and that is only one field I have couple field to do modification to...
    }
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English

Comment: if all those properties are of the same type and the containing objects implement an interface/base class, you can use modelbuilder.Types<>().Configure. Otherwise the given answers are probably the only (kinda) easy way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an extension method that does it for you in one call.

```
class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public T SetupEntity<T>(this T input) where T : EntityTypeBuilder 
    {
        return input
            .Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(40);
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LocationType>().SetupEntity();
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().SetupEntity();
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().SetupEntity();
modelBuilder.Entity<City>().SetupEntity();
```

If you want to make things even shorter, you could use a loop. Load up an array  with the types you need and use it to call the `Entity(Type)` method (instead of the `Entity<T>()` method that is used in your example).

```
Type[] types = new Type[]
{
    typeof(LocationType),
    typeof(Location),
    typeof(Country),
    typeof(City)
};

foreach (var t in types)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity(t).SetupEntity();
}
```

If you are really trying to prove a point, you can do it all in one statement.

```
IEnumerable<Type> types = new Type[]
{
    typeof(LocationType),
    typeof(Location),
    typeof(Country),
    typeof(City)
}
.Select(t => modelBuilder
    .Entity(t)
    .SetupEntity()
)
.ToList();
```

Comment: In the last part (suggestion)  you have a typo error I think and this give a error of Cast the first 2 option works well

Comment: When I try build I got the error in the extension Method said Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Answer (score 1):

[I highly recommedn John Wu's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47228926/209259) but I would make a small modification of adding a const value so you don't have to read through lines of code to determine the default value.  It's pretty minor but worth noting.  (And some naming conventions for readability/maintainability)

```
internal static class EntityTypeBuilderExtensions
{
    private const Default_Name_MaxLength = 40;

    static public T SetupPropertyName<T>(this T input) where T : EntityTypeBuilder 
    {
        return input
            .Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(Default_Name_MaxLength);
    }
}
```

[Here is another extension method I created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005410/extension-methods-for-entitytypeconfiguration-and-datatypepropertyconfiguratio).  It allows you to chain like this:

```
builder.Entity<MyEntity>()
  .ToTable("MyTable", "MySchema")
  .Property(e => e.Name, 
    n => n.IsRequired()
          .HaxMaxLength(10))
  .Property(e => e.City,
    c => c.HasxMaxLength(50));
```